# Autosize panel containing tableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an element containing a panel :

```
this.panel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.panel1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(this.panel1, 2);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel2);
this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
this.panel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10);
this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(264, 100);
this.panel1.TabIndex = 2;
```

This panel contains a tableLayoutPanel. The tableLayoutPanel has 2 rows auto sized containing labels/buttons :

```
this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnCount = 2;
this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.button2, 1, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.button3, 1, 1);
this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label1, 0, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label2, 0, 1);
this.tableLayoutPanel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.tableLayoutPanel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel2.Name = "tableLayoutPanel2";
this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowCount = 2;
this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
this.tableLayoutPanel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(262, 98);
this.tableLayoutPanel2.TabIndex = 0;
```

The heights for the rows are correctly sized. I want that the panel set his height automatically (I will hide some row during execution). Actually I have :

[image]

When I set autoSize = true for panel1 I have :

[image]

How can I do to have this ?

[image]

Panel size must be updated if I add/remove row during execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if "Control.SetBoundsCore" can help you. You will have to create your own panel to use it then.

It seems the reason of your problem is following line of code

```
this.tableLayoutPanel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

Comment: It works thank you. I just had to set autosize = true for the panel and the layout. When I remove a row, I force the height to 0 and the auto resize fit perfectly.